# How to add a mesh to forge viewer v6 using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I need to know how to add meshes to Forge Viewer v6 using Type script.

I went through all the topics and articles and it was working with v4.

Now when I try the following code:

```
    private wallGeometry: THREE.BoxBufferGeometry;

    drawWalls() {

    this.wallGeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(4000, 4000, 100, 1, 1, 1);

    console.log('creating wall geometry');

    this.wallGeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(4000, 4000, 100, 1, 1, 1);

    console.log('creating wall material');

    let wallMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });

    console.log('register wall material');

    this.viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial(
        'dasher-material-vertex',
        wallMaterial,
        true);

    console.log('create Overlay Scene');

    this.viewer.impl.createOverlayScene(this._overlayScene, wallMaterial);

    console.log('wall mesh');

    this.wall = new THREE.Mesh(this.wallGeometry, wallMaterial);
    this.wall.position.set(0, -1000, -2000);

    console.log('add overlay to scene');

    this.addToScene(this.wall);
}

private addToScene(obj: THREE.Object3D) {
    this.viewer.impl.addOverlay(this._overlayScene, obj);
    this.viewer.impl.invalidate(false, false, true);
}
```

I got the following error message:

> THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.
> yr {uuid: "6A27DA63-8F99-4E50-9A99-90BED6CE5B85", name: "", type: "Mesh", parent: null, children: Array(0), …}
> castShadow: false
> children: []
> drawMode: 0
> frustumCulled: true
> geometry: Ii {uuid: "8C6C2DD2-B233-4E98-998C-2307A84D1E4B", name: "", type: "BoxBufferGeometry", index: pi, attributes: {…}, …}
> layers: Pn {mask: 1}
> material: hc {uuid: "9A6A3601-49F6-4D6E-98E1-21C35BF63D80", name: "", type: "MeshPhongMaterial", fog: true, lights: true, …}
> matrix: dn {elements: Array(16)}
> matrixAutoUpdate: true
> matrixWorld: dn {elements: Array(16)}
> matrixWorldNeedsUpdate: false
> name: ""
> parent: null
> position: At {x: 0, y: -1000, z: -2000}
> quaternion: Et {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _w: 1, onChangeCallback: ƒ}
> receiveShadow: false
> renderOrder: 0
> rotation: Cn {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _order: "XYZ", onChangeCallback: ƒ}
> scale: At {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}
> type: "Mesh"
> up: At {x: 0, y: 1, z: 0}
> userData: {}
> uuid: "6A27DA63-8F99-4E50-9A99-90BED6CE5B85"
> visible: true
> eulerOrder: (...)
> id: 3
> modelViewMatrix: dn {elements: Array(16)}
> normalMatrix: Lt {elements: Array(9)}
> useQuaternion: (...)
> **proto**: $n

any ideas??

Edit:
This a snapshot from my DevTools:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to three.js v71 [source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/a95ef3806689f621b33f422ab703ed4ec671b9e0/src/core/Object3D.js#L383-L400), this error is thrown when the inserted object is missing a property called `isObject3D`. I'm not sure if the lack of this property could be caused by Forge Viewer. Try putting a breakpoint right before calling `addToScene` and make sure that the `isObject3D` property is there.

Also, since you're getting this error during *runtime*, it should not be related to TypeScript either.

Comment: I checked for isObject3D and it returns true. Any advice?

Comment: At which point exactly did you check if `isObject3D` is true? Again, based on this [three.js code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/a95ef3806689f621b33f422ab703ed4ec671b9e0/src/core/Object3D.js#L383-L400), the exception is thrown *only* when `object` is null or when `object.isObject3D` is false. Try stepping into the `viewer.impl.addOverlay()` method which then calls `THREE.Object3D.prototype.add()` where the error is thrown.

Comment: I added the check inside the addToScene function.

    private addToScene(obj: THREE.Object3D) {

        console.log('=> obj.isObject3D: ' + obj.isObject3D);

         //this.viewer.impl.scene.add(obj);
         //this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, false);

        this.viewer.impl.addOverlay(this._overlayScene, obj);
        this.viewer.impl.invalidate(false, false, true);
    }

Comment: That way I made sure that I got inside the methode and the object returns true for the isObject property.

Comment: Again, please try and step inside the `addOverlay` method. It simply calls `THREE.Object3D.prototype.add()`, and as you can see in its [implementation](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/a95ef3806689f621b33f422ab703ed4ec671b9e0/src/core/Object3D.js#L383-L400), the only time the exception is thrown is either when `object` is null or undefined, or when `object.isObject3D` is false.

Comment: I did the following: JSON.stringify(obj) then I got the following result:

Comment: {"metadata":{"version":4.5,"type":"Object","generator":"Object3D.toJSON"},"geometries":[{"uuid":"6B6D752F-0789-4ED5-A157-E30ADBF0DDB1","type":"BoxBufferGeometry","width":4000,"height":4000,"depth":100,"widthSegments":1,"heightSegments":1,"depthSegments":1}],"materials":[{"uuid":"48E85A9F-BF7D-41CE-B26D-318819B4274A","type":"MeshPhongMaterial","color":16711680,"emissive":0,"specular":1118481,"shininess":7.5,"depthFunc":3,"depthTest":true,"depthWrite":true}],

Comment: "object":{"uuid":"13E02DC0-5CDE-4B3F-A974-F3EA34B52B4F","type":"Mesh","layers":1,"matrix":[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],"geometry":"6B6D752F-0789-4ED5-A157-E30ADBF0DDB1","material":"48E85A9F-BF7D-41CE-B26D-318819B4274A"}}It seems like the object has no isObject property !!!

Comment: I traced Three.js and updated my topic with a snapshot from devtool. Note the object is named "fi" instead of Mesh. Also I did JSON.stingify(object) and I found no isObject property ??!!

Comment: ´Fi´ is ok, it’s orobably just a minified/uglified version od the symbol Object3D.

Comment: The problem is - the three.js code in your screenshot is *not* from version 71. Look at the link I posted earlier: the code has a line “if (object && object.isObject3D)” but in your screenshot it says “if (object instanceof THREE.Object3D”... so it looks like you’re using a different version of three.js that’s not compatible with the Forge Viewer.

Answer (score -1):

I checked the Three.js version from console, it says 71!!!

[image]